# Is there a common cause of leaky mixer taps?

Tags: plumbing, leak

I bought an ex-rental home that was refreshed for sale with new, but cheap bathroom fittings. All of the single-lever mixer taps developed the same issue inside 18 months: slow water egress at the neck, resulting in limescale crusting the neck and body of the tap. (we're in a very hard water area). I've seen this before on similar models I used myself when I was a cheapskate, so to my mind it's endemic to the cheap end of the market.

[image: Grotty tap]

I want to replace them *reasonably* cheaply and I don't care about style, but I also want something that doesn't develop this fault so quickly. It doesn't seem like one of those areas where simply spending above a certain level is *guarantee* of longevity.

Does this kind of leak have a specific common cause in construction or materials, so I can avoid it?

Comment: You might...install a water softener? Or one of the new-fangled anti-scaling filters that are not a softener, but which prevent scaling by catalyzing nano-crystalization of the dissolved minerals?

Comment: Not a plumber, but maybe somebody who knows something can weigh in on whether a cartridge is worse than conventional valves. My intuition is that cartridges are worse for clogging up.

Comment: Not an answer, but IMO this is unconnected to the hard water. I've lived in very hard water areas all my life and have never seen a mixer tap fail like that, (even cheap ones).

Comment: @Ecnerwal - Already got one :) (It's _very_ hard water) - The main issue though is that, limescale or not, the taps leak from the neck very slowly. I had assumed this was down to poor manufacturing or maybe a cheap variety of ceramic disc. (@SiHa - this is maybe 6-8 months after I last cleaned it)